# probability of the output of a truly random function

Tags: probability

Suppose $ f:\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^l $ is a function sampled uniformly from $ Func_{n \rightarrow l} $.

Given an input $x \in \{0,1\}^n $, can i think of $ f(x) \in \{0,1\}^l $ as a string generated uniformly (The probability to get $ f(x) $ is  $ \frac{1}{2^l})? $

If yes, why?

**EDIT**

$ Func_{n \rightarrow l} $ is the set of all functions f, such that $ f:\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^l.$

Comment: How $Func_{n \rightarrow l}$ is defined please?

Comment: @Yikai, I've edited the question.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: think $f$ as a function from $\{0,\dotsc,2^n\}$ to $\{0,\dotsc,2^l\}$ and count the functions with $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $y \in \{0, 1\}^l$, there are $(2^l)^{2^n - 1}$ functions in $\mathsf{func}_{n\rightarrow l}$ such that $f(x) = y$ because for any $x' \neq x$ and $x' \in \{0, 1\}^n$, there are $2^l$ possible outputs and there are $2^n - 1$ such $x'$s. Now if you sample a function $f$ from $\mathsf{func}_{n\rightarrow l}$, the probability that $f(x) = y$ for some $y \in \{0, 1\}^l$ would be
$$
\frac{(2^l)^{2^n-1}}{{(2^l)}^{2^n}} = \frac{1}{2^l}
$$